Property and components naming
What is the best way to organize work on naming components and properties in a design team? Please advise the naming systems you use. Maybe there will be some useful articles on this topic?

What do you mean by properties? What kind of properties? Of components? And by "design team" you mean design system?

Like most things in UX, it depends on context.

I think you refer to a naming scheme like:
   (A) ComponentGUI.ButtonStart.ColorEnabled
   (B) GUIComponent.StartButton.EnabledColor

The simple answer is: There is no better way, there is only the way everybody agrees upon. To facilitate this, you need a style guide which defines how names (or other things) are supposed to be formed.
All approaches have pros&cons like:
(A) In a A-Z sorted list, all components are grouped, all Buttons and all Colors - but this is done acrosss all boundaries
(B) In a A-Z sorted list, all GUI component elements are consecutive in the list, buttons are sorted by function rather by type, but colors are spread by "Enabled"/"Disabled" etc.
Maybe the A-Z sorted list approach does not apply in your case, then you need to identify the keypoints which distinguishes a good name from a bad name in your particular use case.
There are many ready-to-use style guides available by numerous "big players". Have a look at the Google C++ styleguide for example.
This article shows a short overview on a more design focused approach, considering various categories as colors, fonts etc.
I can also recommend searching terms like "Design Component Naming" which will show you multiple articles about how to build hierarchies or taxonomies of components in various forms.
